# how to remove special char like apostrophes/quotes from filename in php form file upload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have problem in file upload with filename vikas's photo.jpg.i have to upload and insert filename (viaks's photo.jpg)into mysql database table using php script. filename can be handled at client side if possible using jquery.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php It will not remove but escape the quoted string. if you dont want to use quotes at all then you can replace it with http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: You should expand (with examples and output) and post that as an answer @TintuCRaju

Comment: form submission with multipart encoded with file uploading option (input type = file) ,lets file name is vikas's photo.jpg selected ,form submitted.now problem is how to handle filename which has apstorphy 's so that it can be inserted into table using php script.

Comment: @vKr hope my solution addressed your problem.

Comment: use regex for this allowing \w\d only. Use new file name to store uploaded file in your server dir and in your db

Comment: @shahmanthan9 regex is overkill here, plus it will mean you'll be rejecting file uploads which isn't good for user experience. Best to have the application "correct their mistake" in this instance.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. That is the reason why i said that have it in your tmp dir while uploading and rename it in your actual upload dir and save that new name in your DB as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices for this situation. Either escape the quote or remove the quote. If you escape the single quote then your file name will look like `vikas\'s photo.jpg` So it can be inserted to database without any problem. If you remove single quote then your file name will become `vikass photo.jpg`

If you want to escape the quote then you can use `mysql_real_escape_string($string)` since mysql_* functions are depreciated you can also use

`mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

in your case

```
$oldFileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileName = mysql_real_escape_string($oldFileName);
```

If you want to replace quotes then you can use `$fileName = str_replace("'","", $oldFileName);`